# Send multiple rows of pandas dataframe in email python, preferably with html formatting

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pandas, outlook

I have a program that does the following:
1. Signs into our mail server
2. Checks for mail from a specific sender with excel files attached
3. Downloads the files
4. Opens them in pandas
5. Finds relevant information for our team / the person I am developing this application for
6. Sorts the information by date (They are times for our servers to be patched and when they will be going through maintenance)
7. Finds the unique date and time pairs and breaks them into their own dataframes

NOW the final step is I need to send appointments via outlook.  All is fine, I have that built, but I'm not sure how to make the body contain what I want.  I essentially want to add the entirety of the dataframes for that unique day / time pair to be added as a table in the email body.  How can I do this?  Right now I'm just thinking about constructing a large string with for loops but I know pandas and email are two of the most developed and powerful modules, so I'm very curious if I can export a table and add it.

I want to use `outlookemail.HTMLBody = dataframe.to_html()` but I am erroring out here

```
def send_appointment(day, times, newframe):
    if len(newframe)>0:
        outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
        newmail = outlook.CreateItem(1)
        newmail.Start = day+' '+times
        newmail.Subject = 'Server Patching'
        newmail.Duration = 60
        html_string = (newframe.to_html())
        print(html_string)
        newmail.help()
        newmail.HTMLBody = html_string
        #for xy in np.arange(len(newframe)):


        mail.Location = 'redacted'
        mail.MeetingStatus = 1
        mail.Recipients.Add('redacted')
        mail.Send()
```

Comment: _but I am erroring out here_ Always share the entire error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody
this exists for non appointment items, or at least regular mail items, but when setting 
it to be an appointment item, it loses the HTMLBody property 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem